# adding and removing a classList in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am using functional component in react js , in the below code
the class right-panel-active is not being added / is undefined. Someone help to enable the class be added when the button is toggled

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import {
  Modal,
  DropdownMenu
} from '../MaterialUI';

/**
* @author
* @function Header
**/

const Header = (props) => {

  const container = () => {
    document.getElementById('container');
  }    
  const signUpButton = () => {
     container.classList.add('right-panel-active');
  };  
  const signInButton = () => {
     container.classList.remove('right-panel-active');
  };

  return (
    <div className="header">
        <div className="container" id="container">
           <button className="ghost" id="signIn" onClick={signInButton} >Sign In</button>
        </div>
           <div className="overlay-panel overlay-right">
           <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us</p>
                <button className="ghost" id="signUp" onClick={signUpButton} >Sign Up</button>
              </div>
            </div>
  )

}

export default Header
```

Comment: You should not manipulate the DOM directly in React. Can you post your full component?

Comment: i have posted it sorry for the delay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not utilising any of React's functionality.

[Read about state management in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)
and [Event Handlers in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

```js
const Header = (props) => {
 const [isContainerActive, setIsContainerActive] = React.useState(false);
  const signUpButton = () => {
     setIsContainerActive(false);
  };  
  const signInButton = () => {
     setIsContainerActive(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div id="container" className={`container${isContainerActive ? " right-panel-active" : ""}`}>
         <button className="ghost" id="signIn" onClick={signInButton}>Sign In</button>
      </div>
      <div className="overlay-panel overlay-right">
       <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us</p>
       <button className="ghost" id="signUp" onClick={signUpButton}>Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.header {height: 120px;}
.container {float:left;}
.overlay-right {display: none;background: red;float:right;height:100%;}
.right-panel-active ~ .overlay-right {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

PS: I also recommend https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames , or the cx library for className management.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add click event with vanilla js, you could add an React onClick event. You forgot to `return` the container.

```js
// if you use curly braces you must return the value
 const container = () => {
   return document.getElementById('container');
 };    

// or skip the curly braces
 const container = () => 
    document.getElementById('container');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the `React` way of doing,

You have to keep a local state (`useState`) and track the button click and based on the state change update the `class` to the container. You shouldn't directly change the DOM.

Click on the button to see the CSS is adding or not.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isSignUp, setSignUp] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div id="container" className={isSignUp ? "right-panel-active" : ""}>
      <button onClick={() => setSignUp(false)}>SignIn</button>
      <button onClick={() => setSignUp(true)}>SignUp</button>
      //for testing the change
      {isSignUp ? "right-panel-active added" : "right-panel-active removed"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Sample working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-http-qo6du?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for this is to making a state and handle the style by a ternarian

```
    function Welcome(props) {
    const {name} = props;
    return (
        <h1 style={name === 'Sara' ? right-panel-active : right-panel-inactive}>Hello, {name}</h1>
    )}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome name="Sara" />
    </div>
  );
}
```