# How to use classlist in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a navigation bar change from desktop view to mobile view when the page gets resized. Right now I have the navbar code set up into 2 different components, one being the desktop view and one being the mobile view, each with their own respective styling. here is the code I have so far:
first nav bar:

```jsx
const Nav1 = () => {
  return (
    <nav id="desktop-nav">
      <div className="logo">Umar Manzoor</div>
      <div>
        <ul className="nav-links">
          <li>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#experience">Experience</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Nav1;
```

here is the second nav bar component

```jsx
const Nav2 = () => {
  const toggleMenu = () => {
    const menu = document.querySelector(".menu-links");
    const icon = document.querySelector(".lined-icon");
    menu.classList.toggle("open");
    icon.classList.toggle("open");
  };

  return (
    <nav id="lined-nav">
      <div className="logo">Umar Manzoor</div>
      <div className="lined-menu">
        <div className="lined-icon" onClick={toggleMenu()}>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <div className="menu-links">
          <li>
            <a href="#about" onClick={toggleMenu()}>
              About
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#experience" onClick={toggleMenu()}>
              Experience
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#projects" onClick={toggleMenu()}>
              Projects
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact" onClick={toggleMenu()}>
              Contact
            </a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Nav2;
```

and heres some css that goes with it:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  #desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  #lined-nav {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.lined-icon span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 0.3 ease-in-out;
}

.menu-links {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  width: fit-content;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3 ease-in-out;
}

.menu-links a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3 ease-in-out;
}

.menu-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-links.open {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.lined-icon.open span:first-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10px, 5px);
}

.lined-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.lined-icon.open span:last-child {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(10px, -5px);
}

.lined-icon span:first-child {
  transform: none;
}

.lined-icon span:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
}

.lined-icon span:first-child {
  transform: none;
}
```

I'm getting an error when using classlist to add "open" to the class name to differentiate which navbar to show. How can I get around this?

Comment: What is the exact error message? And where is the code that actually uses `classList`?

Comment: when I was debugging I took it out and just logged some stuff, I replaced the logs with how I previously had it. The classList is in the Nav2 component in the toggleMenu() function.

Comment: You still haven't included the actual error message; that's kind of instrumental in solving this.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, not only is there is no need to use the javascript variable `classList` in React, but it is also not a good idea to directly modify the DOM when using React.

React holds references to elements on the page in-memory and makes the most efficient updates when it's told to.  If you bypass React, it won't know about the changes you made.

I believe the creators of the React library want you to only manipulate the DOM through JSX.  This article describes almost your exact use case and an approach to how you can use React's functionality: [adding and removing a classList in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010686/adding-and-removing-a-classlist-in-react-js)